# Hotkey to switch button in confirmation window

Tags: macos, keyboard

Is there a hotkey to choose another button than the highlighted in a confirmation window, like:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable **Full Keyboard Access** in keyboard preferences (Preferences.app). Then You'll be able to switch highlighted buttons by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> and press this button with <kbd>Space bar</kbd>.

[image]

Image taken from this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/473143/how-to-tab-between-buttons-on-an-mac-os-x-dialog-box

Comment: It feels a bit awkward to press space instead of enter, but well, it serves it's purpose. You made my day, thank you very much. :)

Comment: By default Enter is for "all blue" (default) button :)

Comment: @Robin That works...except in Chrome.  If I try to download and overwrite an existing file, I get the all-blue "Cancel" instead of the blue-halo button.  Pressing TAB does nothing.  Pressing Ctrl-F7 toggles the setting (can see it in pref panel), but I can't pick "Replace" with keyboard.